# "Files already in version control are hidden" but I cannot find them them in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

**Steps I made leading up to this problem:**

1. I created a project in Visual Studio Online (TFS) and checked in the entire contents (about 200mb) of a folder called `classic`.
2. I created another project and checked in the entire contents of a folder called `dlls`.
3. I decided that it would make more sense if these two folders were apart of the same project, so I deleted both of the ones I created in steps 1 and 2.
4. I created a new project and mapped it to a folder on my computer that contains both the `classic` and `dlls` folders.
5. In *Visual Studio 2013*, I go into "Source Control Explorer", right click and select "add existing item", and try to add both folders.

In this prompt, none of the files that I need to add are shown! The prompt gives me a message at the top that says "Files already in version control are hidden". If I click through each folder they are blank except for other folders. I verified that the files are still there on my local machine.

[image: add existing files prompt]

The problem is, I deleted those 2 projects in TFS that had the files. Do those projects still exists somewhere? How do I completely get rid of them? Where can I find those files at if they are "already in version control"?

Comment: In step 3 - you deleted them *on the server*?  Or on your local disk?  Did you check in the deletion?  Can you show this folder in Source Control Explorer?

Comment: @edward I deleted both of the projects I had created in Visual Studio Online (on the server) but didn't touch any of my files on my local machine. This is VS Online, and I'm not sure it was possible to "Check In" the deletion. I deleted it per this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357756.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be happening because even though you deleted the files from the server, you local workspace still thinks they are available on the server. The easiest way to recover is if you can delete your workspace and recreate it. Be careful not to delete your local files without creating a backup.

Comment: You were right. What I did was create a temp folder on my desktop and move the files I needed to push to it. I mapped my workspace to this temp folder. Then I was able to push my files from this temp folder to Visual Studio Online. When I was done, I just mapped the workspace back to the original folder and performed a "Get" operation. Now I have all the files uploaded and the correct workspace set. Thanks!